# Can`t build linux binary statically

Tags: windows, unix, gcc, openssl, g++

I using Visual Studio 2022 and debian 7 as remote machine for compiling.

I'm trying to build statically binary or at least openssl statically, help me with this

I have errors:

```
1>/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.a(dso_dlfcn.o) : error : In function dlfcn_globallookup':
1>(.text+0x19) : error : undefined reference to dlopen'

1>/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.a(c_zlib.o) : error : In function zlib_stateful_init':
1>(.text+0x659) : error : undefined reference to deflateInit_'

1>/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.a(c_zlib.o) : error : In function bio_zlib_read':
1>(.text+0x893) : error : undefined reference to inflate'
```

cmd:

```
"g++" -W"switch" -W"no-deprecated-declarations" -W"empty-body" -W"conversion" -W"return-type" -W"parentheses" -W"no-pointer-sign" -W"no-format" -W"uninitialized" -W"unreachable-code" -W"unused-function" -W"unused-value" -W"unused-variable" -std=c++11 -Wall -fno-strict-aliasing -g1 "g++" -fthreadsafe-statics -D "app" -D "NDEBUG" -W"switch" -W"no-deprecated-declarations" -W"empty-body" -W"conversion" -W"return-type" -W"parentheses" -W"no-format" -W"uninitialized" -W"unreachable-code" -W"unused-function" -W"unused-value" -W"unused-variable" -frtti -fno-omit-frame-pointer -std=c11 -fexceptions "1" -o "%(filename).o"
```

linker cmd:

```
-o"unix_x64.out" "3600000" -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Wl,--no-undefined "g++" -l"crypto" -Wl,-z,now -static
```

I found the "-ldl" and "-lz" arguments here and on google, but nothing changes when I add them.

Comment: As you've mentioned `debian`, I recommend you change your `unix` tag to `linux`. You'll increase the number of potential readers from 24K to 223K. Good luck.